# How much size is too large for Session on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I want to load a text file in Session.

The file size is about 50KB ~ 100KB.

When user trigger the function in my page. it will create the Session.

My Server's RAM is about 8GB. and the max users is about 100

Because there will be a script run in background to collect IP and MAC in LAN.
The script continues write data into text file.
In the same time, the webpage will using Ajax to fetch fresh data from text file.and display on the page.

Is it suitable to implement by session to keep the result? or any better way to achieve ? 
Thanks ~

The Python script will collect the data in the LAN in 1 ~ 3 minutes.(Background job)
To avoid blocking for 1~3 minutes. I will use Ajax to fetch the data in text file (continuing added by Python script) and show on the page.
And my user should carry the information cross pages. So I want to store the data in Session.

```
00:02:D1:19:AA:50:  172.19.13.39
00:02:D1:13:E8:10:  172.19.12.40
00:02:D1:13:EB:06:  172.19.1.83
C8:9C:DC:6F:41:CD:  172.19.12.73
C8:9C:DC:A4:FC:07:  172.19.12.21
00:02:D1:19:9B:72:  172.19.13.130
00:02:D1:13:EB:04:  172.19.13.40
00:02:D1:15:E1:58:  172.19.12.37
00:02:D1:22:7A:4D:  172.19.11.84
00:02:D1:24:E7:0F:  172.19.1.79
00:FD:83:71:00:10:  172.19.11.45
00:02:D1:24:E7:0D:  172.19.1.77
00:02:D1:81:00:02:  172.19.11.58
00:02:D1:24:36:35:  172.19.11.226
00:02:D1:1E:18:CA:  172.19.12.45
00:02:D1:0D:C5:A8:  172.19.1.45
74:27:EA:29:80:3E:  172.19.12.62
```

Comment: Could you explain why you want to load a text file into a session (what does it contain)? I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: Hi Damine, I update the additional information in the tail of the post

Answer (score 0):

Why does this need to be stored in the browser? Couldn't you fire off what you're collecting to a data store somewhere?

Anyway, assuming you HAD to do this, and the example you gave is pretty close to the data you'll actually be seeing, you have a lot of redundant data there. You could save space for the IPs by creating a hash pointing to each successive value, I.E.

`{172 => {19 => {13 => [39], 12 => [40, 73, 21], 1 => [83]}}}` ...etc. Similarly for the MAC addresses. But again, you can probably simplify this problem a LOT by storing the info you need somewhere other than the session.